# How to set variable based on table with matching name?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables, listobject

I am trying to reference a variable name in my code rather than the value of the variable.

A file that is loaded into this file can change, columns added or removed, or renamed.

I made a mapping table to some of the columns and if they were to be outputted or not along with the shortened column name (which name will not change). The idea is that if the column names were to change the rest of the code doesn't have to be amended as the shortened version will rename the same. I just need to update the long version on the mapping table.

The code I am trying to do is:

- Declare the shared variable
- Loop through the variables listed in an array
- If a specific column contains that variable name, then set the variable value as another column in that same row.

```vb
Public Col_ColTitle         As String
Public Col_KeepRemove       As String
Public Col_HiPort           As String
Public Col_FundName         As String
Public Col_Status           As String
Public Col_CompBD           As String
Public Col_IMA              As String
Public Col_Deadline         As String
Public Col_ClientRep        As String
Public Col_ClientRepSO      As String
Public Col_InvDir           As String
Public Col_InvDirSO         As String
Public Col_Comments         As String
Public Col_CManager         As String
Public Col_CDirector        As String

Sub GetDataValues()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim vCols As Variant
    
    Set tbl_ColNames = ws_Settings.ListObjects("tbl_ColNames")

    vCols = Array(Col_ColTitle, _
                    Col_KeepRemove, _
                    Col_HiPort, _
                    Col_FundName, _
                    Col_Status, _
                    Col_CompBD, _
                    Col_IMA, _
                    Col_Deadline, _
                    Col_ClientRep, _
                    Col_ClientRepSO, _
                    Col_InvDir, _
                    Col_InvDirSO, _
                    Col_Comments, _
                    Col_CManager, _
                    Col_CDirector)
    

    On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
    For i = LBound(vCols) To UBound(vCols)
           
        With tbl_ColNames
            For r = 1 To .ListRows.Count
                If .DataBodyRange(r, .ListColumns("Code Name").Index).Value = vCols(i) Then
                    vCols(i) = .DataBodyRange(r, .ListColumns("Column Title").Index).Value
                    
                    Debug.Print vCols(i)
                    
                End If
            Next r
        End With
        
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
    MsgBox "Test"

End Sub
```

Comment: `vCols` is just an array of empty strings.  Do you populate it at some point?

Comment: That’s what I am trying to do. I have a list of variables I am trying to populate using the loop. The loop is to look into a table and get the value if a column where the preceding column contains the variable name

Comment: `If .DataBodyRange(r, .ListColumns("Code Name").Index).Value = vCols(i) Then` - no values in `vCols()` are populated,  except with empty strings so you'll not get a match unless the cell value is empty...

Comment: That said, you can't in VBA access a variable using its name.  If you need to do something like this then you should use a Scripting Dictionary instead.